# Flutter on real device start working after the second click (touch)

Tags: flutter, dart, click

When I'm testing the same app on the emulator, it works fine. It responds to the first touch.

However, on the real device, the first touch doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please describe your problem in more detail?

Comment: Do you mean tuch on the launcher to open the app or some gesture detector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using **CustomTheme** widget above **Material**, to customize the theme according to the state of the app.

The first touch was on the **CustomTheme**, and then it starts to get the clicks on **Material** widget.

Solved!